# Como melhorar esse código sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Gostaria de melhorar esse código para que NÃO REPETISSE O MESMO CÓDIGO NOS DOIS IFS.
Não estou afim de usar procedures pois não vejo necessidade.

```
DECLARE @Ordem VARCHAR (7), @Valor VARCHAR(10)
SET @Ordem = 'E'
IF @Ordem = 'E'

BEGIN
  SELECT 
  P.ParcDocFinDupNum,P.ParcDocFinSeq,P.ParcDocFinDesmPag,P.ParcDocFinDataEmissao,P.ParcDocFinDataVenc,
  P.BcoNum,P.TipoCobCod,P.ParcDocFinValOrig,P.ParcDocFinValor, P.DocFinChv,E.EntNome,
  D.EmpCod,D.DocFinTipoLanc,D.DocFinProjecao, D.DocFinChv, D.EntCod, D.DocFinEspec, GetDate() as DataHoje
  FROM DOC_FIN D 
INNER JOIN PARC_DOC_FIN P ON D.EntCod = P.EntCod 
INNER JOIN ENTIDADE E ON E.EntCod = P.EntCod
WHERE  
D.DocFinTipoLanc = 'PAG' 
AND ('Todos' = 'Não' OR D.DocFinProjecao = 'Não')
ORDER BY E.EntNome ASC, RAND()

END

IF @Ordem = 'V'
SELECT 
  P.ParcDocFinDupNum,P.ParcDocFinSeq,P.ParcDocFinDesmPag,P.ParcDocFinDataEmissao,P.ParcDocFinDataVenc,
  P.BcoNum,P.TipoCobCod,P.ParcDocFinValOrig,P.ParcDocFinValor, P.DocFinChv,E.EntNome,
  D.EmpCod,D.DocFinTipoLanc,D.DocFinProjecao, D.DocFinChv, D.EntCod, D.DocFinEspec, GetDate() as DataHoje
  FROM DOC_FIN D 
INNER JOIN PARC_DOC_FIN P ON D.EntCod = P.EntCod 
INNER JOIN ENTIDADE E ON E.EntCod = P.EntCod
WHERE  
D.DocFinTipoLanc = 'PAG' 
AND ('Todos' = 'Não' OR D.DocFinProjecao = 'Não')
ORDER BY convert(varchar,P.ParcDocFinDataVenc,103), E.EntNome ASC

END
```

Comment: (1) É MySQL ou SQL Server? // (2) Avalie o trecho `'Todos' = 'Não'`

Comment: pelo que entendi, a única diferença entre os _ifs_ é a ordenação. É isso mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar uma expressão CASE WHEN [expressao booleana] THEN [expressao] END na cláusula ORDER BY, para retirar os IFs... ELSEs:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/70e6e2d4-39f3-4d1b-b8d4-745d9c52464f/case-no-order-by-possivel?forum=520

EDIT: no seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
...
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @Ordem = 'E' THEN E.EntNome
     WHEN @Ordem = 'V' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, P.ParcDocFinDataVenc, 103)
END ASC,
CASE WHEN @Ordem = 'E' THEN RAND()
     WHEN @Ordem = 'V' THEN E.EntNome
END ASC
```